# Download file after submission entityform on Drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

i'm working on a projet (Drupal 7).
I created a form using entityform module.
What i need to do is to download a file after the form submission.
How can i do that ? 
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You need to tell us what file needs to be downloaded afterwards. An existing file? Something derived from the submitted form? Also how will it be downloaded? Give the user a link? Start the download immediately?

Comment: an existing file. It's the same file for all submissions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to alter the form, add your submit handler function and do your download functionality in it, what ever it is. Check first answer here:

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33339/how-to-use-form-submit-hook